# Perl XML parsing with CSS selectors

Tags: xml, perl, namespaces, css-selectors

Does anybody know a Perl library that can parse XML documents and enables me to select nodes via CSS Selectors and namespace support?

Background:
I was trying to parse a document with a default namespace with the perl libxml package but it never returned anything until I removed the default namespace from the root node.

This is what I found on the topic:
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2003-April/msg00143.html

So a simple example would be a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns">
  <message>Hi</message>
</root
```

XPath `//message` wouldn't give me any results with perl libxml. I know that the library is doing it's job perfectly fine but I still need to parse that stuff, so I figured a CSS selector based library might be more successful.

Comment: Can you provide an example what you want to parse and what you want to get?

Comment: Pro tip: the graphical interface to libxml [Xacobeo](http://p3rl.org/Xacobeo) makes it easy to mess with XPath. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fOTus.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with anything you can throw at libxml.

```
use strictures;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML qw();
BEGIN { HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML->replace_original; }
use Web::Query qw();

print Web::Query->new_from_html(<<'MARKUP')->find('root > message')->text;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns">
<message>Hi</message>
</root>
MARKUP

1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to Web::Query. I hoped to find something more CPANish. But this will do nicely.

Comment: Indeed, so even the boss will be happy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'test.xhtml');

print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($_), "\n" for ($xp->find('root/message')->get_nodelist);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code works on the example xml I provided as well as on my production data. I has almost the same code except that I used XML::Parser, which didn't find the message node.

Comment: The question was about CSS selectors.

Comment: @user1215106: I was indeed looking for a CSS selector library because I generally prefer it over XPath. This is why you get an upvote but no accept.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you tell it too XML::Twig will happily ignore namespaces. You would get to `message` either by setting a handler on the element name, or by using an XPath query like `my @messages= $twig->findnodes( '//message')`

To use a handler you would write:

```
XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { message => \&process_message })
         ->parsefile( "my.xml"); )

sub process_message
  { my( $twig, $message)= @_;
    print $message->text;
  }
```

Comment: Can you rewrite this to use HTML-Selector-XPath so that we arrive at the node through a CSS selector?

Comment: no ;--) XML::Twig lets you use `tag.class` though, which I often find to be a useful shortcut